# how can i generate 2 binaries, one in fortran and one in cxx, with cmake

Tags: cmake, fortran

I have a library that must be linked to 2 main codes, one in fortran and on in cxx.

I have this library in `src/lib/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(mylib a.f90 b.c c.cc)
```

and in `src/main/CMakeLists.txt`, I have:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(mymain1 mymain1.f90)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(mymain1 mylib)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(mymain2 mymain2.cc)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(mymain2 mylib)
```

When compiling `mymain1`, it use the CXX compiler to link instead of the Fortran one.

How can I tell cmake to use Fortran to link `mymain1` and CXX to link `mymain2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may directly affect on language used for linking with [LINKER_LANGUAGE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/LINKER_LANGUAGE.html) *property*:

```
# Use Fortran compiler for link 'mymain1' executable
set_target_properties(mymain1 PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE Fortran)
```

---

Another way could be "teach" CMake to properly choose linker.

Without the library CMake would **correctly** select Fortran linker for `mymain1` as it compiled only from Fortran sources, and C++ linker for `mymain2` as it compiled only from C++ sources.

But linking with the library messes CMake: because the library `mylib` is compiled from sources on *several* languages, CMake selects linker for it using some "preference scores" for languages (see [CMAKE_<LANG>_LINKER_PREFERENCE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_LANG_LINKER_PREFERENCE.html) variable). More likely, C++ "beats" Fortran in your case.

Moreover, when select linker language for `mymain1`, CMake take into account language for the static library `mylib`. Because of that C++ wins even for the executable built from Fortran sources only.

You may disable propagating library's language to the executable using variables [CMAKE_<LANG>_LINKER_PREFERENCE_PROPAGATES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_LANG_LINKER_PREFERENCE_PROPAGATES.html):

```
# <place this *before* adding executables>
# Do not propagate language of C++ libraries to the executables.
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINKER_PREFERENCE_PROPAGATES OFF)
```